# Set a property in a Control Template

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I want to assign an URI on my Image control. The following XAML is in a UserControl.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{StaticResource ImageClick}" x:Name="imageButton">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="300" x:Name="image" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

I have in code-behind a dependency property with the image's URL :

```
public string ImageUrl
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ImageUrlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ImageUrlProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageUrl.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageUrlProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ImageUrl", typeof(string), typeof(ImageControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

What is the best practice to assign the Source property of my Image which is in a ControlTemplate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a content presenter and then merely put your image in the button's content.

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{StaticResource ImageClick}"
        x:Name="imageButton">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
        <Image MaxHeight="100"
               MaxWidth="300"
               x:Name="image" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In your code use a PropertyChangedCallback to set the source of the image.